# How to access the paragraph added using javascript to my html page using flask?

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I am trying to make a todo list using flask, html, css and javascript. My objective is to access the items using flask that I added to my html using javascript.

Here is my file named "daily.html"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Daily Goals</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="....">
</head>
<body>
  <script src= "...."></script>
  <div class="addItem">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="text...">
    <span onclick="newDiv()" class="addList">Add</span>
  </div>
  <form method='POST' action='/paras'>
  <div class="covered" id="fullOn">
    <h2 id="para">Add your daily todo lists</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="item">     #this is where the todo list will be added
    <p>{{itemName}}</p>
  </div>
  <p><input value = "Do it" type='SUBMIT'></p>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my javascript file name "daily.js"

```
var myNodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("P");
var i;

function newDiv() {       #This function will add the list to my html
  var item = document.createElement("p");
  item.innerHTML = document.getElementById("myInput").value
  item.setAttribute("class","item")
  document.getElementById("fullOn").appendChild(item);
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  item.appendChild(span);
  var classItem = document.getElementsByClassName('item');

  span.style.marginLeft = "200px";
  span.onclick = function() {
    var div = this.parentElement;
    div.style.display = "none";
  }
  item.onclick = function() {
    item.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
  }

}
```

Here is python code named "navigation.py". The below chunk of code takes me to "daily.html" page.

```
@app.route('/goals/daily')
def daily_page():
    return render_template("daily.html")
```

The below chuck tries to access the list added to "daily.html"

```
@app.route('/paras',methods=['POST'])
def get_paragraphs():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        paras = request.get_json()
        print(paras)
```

I expect my python code to print out the todo list to terminal. But instead it shows error in the terminal.

```
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The   function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

Comment: the error message tells you exactly what's wrong. You need to have your `get_paragraphs` function return a valid response - typically that's either with `render_template` or `redirect`

Comment: @RobinZigmond  I tried render_template, and it returns nothing.

Comment: paras = request.get_json() will get nothing because you did not have input, textarea, select, ... in your form. The form had only a submit button.

Comment: @ASSILITaher but I added my todo's using using javascript

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of solutions to implement todo list using flask and JavaScript. Please find this basique solution:

First, you need to add the total number of todo list added by the user:

```
<input type='text' value='0'
name='total-todo-list'
id='total-todo-list' style='display:none' />
```

Second, you need to add the todo list inputs to your form like this:

```
<input type='text' value='drink coffee'
name='todo-list-1' style='display:none' />
<input type='text' value='sleep'
name='todo-list-2' style='display:none' />
```

So, the form in `daily.html` file will be like this:

```
<form method='POST' action='/paras' id='some-unique-id'>
  <input type='text' value='0'
  name='total-todo-list' id='total-todo-list'
  style='display:none' />

  <div class="covered" id="fullOn">
    <h2 id="para">Add your daily todo lists</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="item">     #this is where the todo list will be added
    <p>{{itemName}}</p>
  </div>
  <p><input value = "Do it" type='SUBMIT'></p>
</form>
```

And the `daily.js` file will be similar to this:

```
function newDiv() {
  // put your old code here.
  var total_todo_list = parseInt($('#total-todo-list').val());
  total_todo_list = total_todo_list + 1
  $('#total-todo-list').val(total_todo_list)

  todo = document.getElementById("myInput").value
  html_ = "<input type='text' value='" + todo +
  "' name='todo-list-" + total_todo_list + 
  "' style='display:none' />";
  $("#some-unique-id").append(html_);
}
```

And the server file will be similar to this:

```
@app.route('/paras',methods=['POST'])
def get_paragraphs():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        total = int(request.form['total-todo-list'])
        todo = []
        for i in range(total):
            if i != 0:
               todo_item = request.form['todo-list-' + str(i)]
               todo.append(todo_item)
        print todo
        # do some stuff
        return 'POST ok'

    return 'GET ok'
```